# Invalid token session. Please login again. in Opencart admin

Tags: .htaccess, session, opencart

I have a problem with an Opencart installation where i cannot access the admin for the site on the live domain - it does work however on the development domain with the same host and setup.

There is no access token being passed to the URL - i just keep being redirected back to the login screen with the error message 'Invalid token session. Please login again.'.

If i remove the .htaccess file the admin will work as expected, as will the homepage, but all subpages then error with a page not found error.

I have tried all the suggestions i have found for example adding session.save_path = /tmp; to the php.ini and adding order allow, deny etc. to the htaccess.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix:
**Step one:**
you should install vqmod and then you should create notepad.txt file and paste following code into the txt file:

```
<?xml version="1.5" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
<id>Keep Admin Users Logged In - Opencart 2.x</id>
<version>1.1</version>
<vqmver>2.5.1</vqmver>
<author>Nt Solutions</author>
<file name="admin/controller/user/user.php">
<operation error="skip">
<search position="after"><![CDATA[class ControllerUserUser extends Controller {]]></search>
<add trim="true"><![CDATA[
public function pingUser() {
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode(1));
}
]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
<file name="admin/controller/common/footer.php">
<operation error="skip">
<search position="before"><![CDATA[return $this->load->view('common/footer.tpl', $data);]]></search>
<add trim="true"><![CDATA[
if (isset($this->session->data['token'])) {
$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
}
]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
<file name="admin/view/template/common/footer.tpl">
<operation error="skip">
<search position="before"><![CDATA[</body>]]></search>
<add trim="true"><![CDATA[
<?php if (isset($token)) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php?route=user/user/pingUser&token=<?php echo $token; ?>",
dataType: "json",
timeout: 10000
});
}, 15000);
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
</modification>
```

**step two:** make SAVE AS: ntsolutions.xml
**step three:** copy and paste the file ntsolutions.xml into the  *\vqmod\xml
**step four:** clear the cache in the admin Extensions/ modifications and click refresh button

Answer (score 0):

First check your PHP version , if it's under 5.2 it might show those errors. Change it to PHP 5.4+

Add this to your .htaccess  to change the php version

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php55 .php
```

the **55** stands for the php version (5.5)

Try to access your site with www and without and see if there is any difference

Make sure you have uploaded all of the files from the rar folder when you install Opencart

And also make sure that your OC isn't in a subfolder

**example** : example.com/opencart (In this case opencart will have issues working)